# Loading large number of images without affecting user experience

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is basically a design question.

**Preface**

I have a web page which shows a list of thumbnails. The number of images can be anything, maybe hundreds.

What I need to do is this?

- Get the number of total thumbnails.
- Get the web url for each image.
- Load each thumbnail into a box (div) and add each box dynamically to
  scrollable container div.
- User should be able to interact with the boxes ASAP.

I have other AJAX calls happening in the page.

The default method, set the `src` to each box and add it to the container. When loading stops, the image shows. The problem is that, all these image loading will hog the network and my other AJAX calls may timeout, which I can't allow. Also, the user should see the page as loading complete (loading bar should not show activity).

**My Solution**

The solution I have come up is this:

- Use a local image as space holder.
- Set the src of all the boxes as local image.
- Change the src for first image to the web url.
- When `onload` of the image fires, change the src of next image and so on.

Pros:

- Only one image will be loading at a time.
- User will be able to interact with the boxes.

Cons:

- Only one image at a time may be a waste of bandwidth (what about 5 images at a time?)
- What happens if user scrolls to the end, the images won't show up until all the other images have loaded.

**Your opinion**

I need expert opinions on how to improve this solution.

Requirements:

1. Some bandwidth should be available for other AJAX calls
2. User should be able to interact with the page.

Questions:

Is this solution having any other issues?

Is this cross browser?

Am I correct in saying this will not affect the other AJAX calls?

Comment: Is it possible for the server to return all the thumbnails as a single image sprite so that you only load 1 single image? (Server side image processing will be required.) You can then use CSS to "chop up" the thumbnails and display them where appropriate. See: http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Comment: @WinnieTong That is a great idea, but I don't have control over the server. Thanks...

Comment: If you have PHP, you can use that to process the images. http://php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.image.php

Comment: @Mooseman I know it will be much easier if I can do it server side, but I have to be at client side.

Comment: If you don't have control over the server side, what information do you have and in what structure? Can you get paged data? Paging the images, fetching only a handful at a time, and then fetching the next page as the user scrolls or as the images finish loading would be a good approach.

Comment: @jxpx777 Each of the images are independent, I have the URL for all the images. Yeah, I can try to get all the images for the current page. But, I would have to keep track of the scroll for that. What happens if I am getting a page full of images and user scrolls, if I go and get that page too, then the initial problem of network hogging comes, right?

Comment: What languages can you use on your server?

Comment: @Mooseman This is not a server side question. I don't have access to server. I want to manage this using JavaScript/jquery.

Comment: Just because you don't have administrative access to your server doesn't mean you can't run PHP. Try making a PHP file with the below code and uploading it.

`<?php echo'You have PHP!'; ?>`

Comment: @Mooseman I know that. I am getting these images from third party image hosting and I don't think I can do anything better even if I have a server in between. Still, suppose I have access to a tomcat server. What can I do then?

Comment: You can use the server to copy the images from the source, and then put them together into a sprite using PHP. Then the 'in between' server serves the image file to the user. Beware of CPU usage.